# How to insert a backslash in front of each pipe

Tags: java, string, replaceall, asciidoc

I want to insert a backslash in front of each pipe:

```
// What i want
MyList.replaceAll(item -> item.replaceAll("|" , "\|")); 
// what i´ve tried that does not work
MyList.replaceAll(item -> item.replaceAll("\\|" , "\\|"));
```

when executing the code I get "illegal escape character in string literal".

appreciate your help
Thx :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you want literal backslashes in the strings? That's a nice puzzler:

```
String item = "This | is | a | sample".replaceAll("\\|" , "\\\\|");
System.out.println(item);
```

prints:

```
This \| is \| a \| sample
```

**Why is this?**
You have to escape literal backslashes with another backslash in Java string literals. The same applies to special RegEx symbols. So in the above example, you want to match every literal `|`, so we put a `\` before it (RegEx escape) and another `\` (Java string escape for the first `\`).

Answer (score 2):

[`String::replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) takes a regex as first parameter - on how to use it check [mumpitz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58484294/4956907).

As other soultion you could use [`String::replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)) method which takes which takes two `CharSequence` parameters :

```
String item = "This | is | a | sample".replace("|" , "\\|");
System.out.println(item);
```

Output :

```
This \| is \| a \| sample
```

I used example provided by mumpitz - I hope that is ok :)

Comment: This is even better than my answer, because the use of Regular Expressions is really not needed in this case. Useless overhead. +1